# Python Tkinter: Delete all contents from ListBox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

Hey guys pretty sure this is a simple fix, but I can't find anything. Basically I'm filling a listbox, and I need it to update (pseudo update) whenever a user clicks a label in the listbox.

My only problem is deleting all contents from the listbox. Below I have the function I implemented. Thank you in advance!

```
class SocketThreadedTask(threading.Thread):
def _init_(self, socket, callback):
    threading.Thread._init_(self)
    self.socket = socket
    self.callback = callback
    self.allChannels = None
    self.privateChannels = {}
    self.publicChannels = {}
    self.channelMessages = {}

def run(self):
    channels = None
    messages = None
    while True:
        try:
            message = self.socket.receive()
            if message[0] == "channels":
                self.allChannels = message[1]
                for key, value in self.allChannels.items():
                    if key[0] == '+':
                        oldKey = key
                        newKey = key[1:]
                        self.allChannels[newKey] = value
                        del self.allChannels[oldKey]
                        self.publicChannels[key] = value
                    elif key[0] == '-':
                        key = key[1:]
                        self.privateChannels[key] = value
                message = message[0]
                self.callback(None, self.allChannels, None)
            elif message[0] == "messages":
                self.channelMessages = messages = message[1]
                message = message[0]
                self.callback(message, None, messages)
            else:
                message = message[0]
                self.callback(message, None, None)
            if message == '/quit':
                self.callback('> You have been disconnected from the chat room.')
                self.socket.disconnect()
                break
        except OSError:
            break

class ChatWindow(tk.Frame):
def _init_(self, parent):
    tk.Frame._init_(self, parent)

    self.initUI(parent)

def initUI(self, parent):
    self.messageScrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(parent, orient=tk.VERTICAL)
    self.messageScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="ns")

    self.messageTextArea = tk.Text(parent, bg="white", state=tk.DISABLED, yscrollcommand=self.messageScrollbar.set, wrap=tk.WORD)
    self.messageTextArea.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky="nsew")

    # list of users
    self.usersListBox = tk.Listbox(parent, bg="white")
    self.usersListBox.grid(row=0, column=4, padx=5, sticky="nsew")

    self.entryField = entry.BaseEntry(parent, placeholder="Enter message.", width=80)
    self.entryField.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky="we")

    self.send_message_button = tk.Button(parent, text="Send", width=10, bg="#CACACA", activebackground="#CACACA")
    self.send_message_button.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, sticky="we")

def update_window(self, message, channels, messages):
    if (message is None) and (messages is None):
        self.refresh_users(channels)
    elif (channels is None) and (message is None):
        self.refresh_messages(messages)
    elif (channels is None) and (messages is None):
        self.update_chat_window(message)

def refresh_users(self, channels = {}):
     self.usersListBox.delete(0, END)
     self.usersListBox.insert(0, "Channels")
     if bool(channels) is True:
          count = 1
          for key, value in channels.items():
               label = Label(self.userListBox, text=key)
               label.pack()
               label.bind(None, self.switch(label.cget("text")))
               self.usersListBox.insert(count, label)
               count += 1
```

[image: This is before I message, on the first update.]

I will attach 2 images[image: When anyone on the channel speaks, it's supposed to update the listbox.]

Comment: `if (channels) is True` looks strange to me. Since you're calling `channels.items` later, I assume you expect channels to be a dict. But if channels is a dict, then `if (channels) is True` will never be True. I suspect you heard the fact "non-empty dicts are True in a boolean context", but that doesn't mean `some_dict is True` will ever be True, it means `bool(some_dict)` can be True.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to add that. I'll edit it now.

Comment: Ok, looking a little better now. But it's hard to tell what the problem is from just this one little piece of code. Are you getting an error? Is the program running without errors, but not doing what you want? If so, what is it doing, and what do you want it to be doing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've updated this post with more relevant information.

Comment: Are you asking how to delete everything in a listbox (which is documented), or how to fix your code so that it does it at the right time? You've posted a whole lot of code that seems irrelevant to clearing a listbox.

Comment: I'm asking why my listbox is not deleting the elements inside of it properly. I know that in order to delete an element, it's `listbox.delete(0, END)` to delete from element 0 to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it's not crashing. I don't see your import statements, but contextually in your code you may have to write:

```
 self.usersListBox.delete(0, tk.END)
```

I think you imported Tkinter as tk, and END is a component of tk. Because it's not defined as such, is it possible that END is a variable in some wildcard-ed library or somewhere else in your code?

Specify `tk.END` or `"end"` in your delete function as in the example above and that would prevent this error.